# Apply filters if Valid using lambda C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to build a filter for a `Get()` method using entity and lambda in my .net Core 2.2 application.

I'm submitting some data trough postman and trying to fetch based on the filtered params, when debbugging, they go trough it as should, but the final result is the complete list of objects, as there is no filter at all.

I'm using memory database since I don't have any database available yet.

What am I missing?

```
public List<Analysis> Get(Analysis filter)
{
    #region Filter Validation

    IQueryable<Analysis> analysis = dbContext.Analysis;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.BusinessLine))
        analysis.Where(a => a.BusinessLine == filter.BusinessLine);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Requisition))
        analysis.Where(a => a.Requisition == filter.Requisition);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Clue))
        analysis.Where(a => a.Clue == filter.Clue);

    if (filter.DateFrom.HasValue)
        analysis.Where(a => a.CreationDate >= filter.DateFrom);            

    if (filter.DateTo.HasValue)
        analysis.Where(a => a.CreationDate <= filter.DateTo);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Text))
    {
        analysis.Where(a => a.Requisition.Contains(filter.Text) ||
                        a.InsuranceClaimCity.Contains(filter.Text));
    }

    #endregion

    return analysis.ToList();
}
```

Comment: You forgot the assignment `analysis = analysis.Where(....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the result of the Where methods in the variable again. Where returns a changed set, instead of changing the current set.

Answer (score 1):

The Where method returns a new instance which implements `IEnumerable<Analysis>`, it does not alter the original collection. You should use an assignment, if you want to keep using the same variable for it.

```
var analysisList = analysis.ToList();

analysisList = analysisList.Where(a => a.BusinessLine == filter.BusinessLine);// make this assignment for all the rest of filtering.
```